# are calculations in ideals associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say if we have $I+a+bX+cX^2+I+I$, can we rearrange the order to how we like?

Because you can always imagine $0+I$ when the ideals are written consecutively.

Comment: Are you asking about associativity or commutativity?

Comment: both to be honest

Comment: So I presume this is all happening in a ring $R$, and $X$ is any subset of $R$, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$?

Comment: yeah, sorry I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations between sets are great, once you get used to them. They shorten your notation and often give you a more intuitive idea about what is happening.

However, as long as you are still asking questions like this one, it means that the notation is still confusing to you (nothing wrong with that, it confuses the hell out of me as well). In that case, it's always nice to remember what $aX$ and $b+Y$ mean when $a,b$ are elements and $X,Y$ are sets.

By definition, you have, for elements $a,b$ and sets $X,Y$:

- $aX = \{y|\exists x\in X: y=ax\}$
- $a + X = \{y|a+X, x\in X: y=a+x\}$
- $X + Y = \{z|x + y, x\in X, y\in Y:z=x+y\}$

Knowing all this, you can now easily see that, since you are dealing with addition, you have commutativity and associativity, since $$(X+Y) + Z = (Y + C)\\
X+Y = Y+X$$
can be proven from the definitions.

Comment: ok that is fine. So what if you have one set only. So would $2+ I= I+2$?

Comment: @snowman Well, since $a + X = \{a\}+X$, that one should be easy to see.

Comment: oh so yeah it is then...

Comment: @snowman Indeed. Also, knowing that $I$ is an ideal also means that $I+I = I$, so your expression can be somewhat simplified into $a+bX + cX^2 + I$.

Comment: say if $X\in\mathbb{F}_7[X]$, is it possible to calculate something like 2(X+I) or should we always avoid things like this?

Comment: just realised 2(X+I)=X+I+X+I=2X+I

Comment: if its not too much to ask, would you please have a look at my latest thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234369/writing-quotient-rings-elements-in-a-form because it relates to this thread a lot... whenever you get time.